# Release crowdloan funds before lease expires?

Tags: parachain, crowdloan, governance

would it be possible to deregister a parachain and release tokens locked from crowdloan using governance in relay chain?

Answer (score 0):

Governance in the relay chain can do this, yes.

There are `Root` level functions in both the Crowdloan pallet and the Parachain Slots pallet which would enable both the crowdloan to dissolve earlier than intended, and for a parachain to lose it slot.

These actions would need to be agreed upon by majority of token holders.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/5451):

> A para becomes locked automatically when it is upgraded to a parachain
> or is part of a crowdloan.
>
> ---
>
> To unlock the parachain, either ROOT or the parachain itself must call
> the `remove_lock` function.
>
> While the parachain is unlocked, the parachain registration owner has
> access to the following functions:
>
> 1. `deregister` - Which registers a parachain from the system.
> 2. `swap` - Which signals that a parachain is willing to trade leases with another parachain.
> 3. `schedule_code_upgrade` - Which allows a new runtime code to be scheduled at a future block, just like if the parachain were to
>    schedule an upgrade.
> 4. `set_current_head` - Which allows new head data to be set for a parachain.
>
> While a parachain is unlocked, the chain should be considered the same
> as if the `Sudo` module was installed on that chain. For many
> parachains, there will be a period where being unlocked will be
> helpful for onboarding, and at a future point, the chain can be
> locked. Until then, the lock status of a chain should be a
> consideration for any users participating in crowdloans, using that
> chain, or even other parachains seeking to interact with that chain.

Comment: will users be able to claim their crowdloan stake when the parachain has been deregistered?